# How to query multiple filters based on the price inputs? javascript - web - firestore

Tags: javascript, filter, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a real-estate website, and i am about to finish it. However, i am stuck on filtering the properties based on the user input fields. I am trying now with only the price range inputs, but its not working. And there is no error in the console.
this is the code for getting the data from database and filtering:

```
const searchMin = Number(document.getElementById('min').value); 
const searchMax = Number(document.getElementById('max').value);
// get data from the cloud Database and display on the home page
db.collection('properties')
.where("price", ">=", searchMin)
.where("price", "<=", searchMax)
.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    setupProp(snapshot.docs)

});
```

And here is where i am displaying them to the home page:

```
// Displaying the properties to the HomePage
const setupProp = data => {
  let html = '';
  data.forEach(doc => {
    const info = doc.data();
    let li = `
    <div class="col s12 l4 items">
      <div class="card" style="height: 407px;">
        <div class="card-image">
          <a href="property.html?${doc.id}">
          <img src="${info.image[0]}" style="height: 228px;"></a>
          <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red center status">${info.type}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <span><b class="house-title">${info.title}</b></span><br>
          <span><b class="blue-text price">${info.price}</b> &#36;</span><br>
          <span class="material-icons blue-text">room</span>
          <span><b class="city">${info.city}</b></span><br>
          <span class="material-icons blue-text">single_bed</span>
          <span><b class="rooms">${info.rooms}</b> rooms</span>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    `;

    html += li

    showingProp.innerHTML = html; 
  })
}
```

Comment: "it's not working" is not a lot to go on.  If you step through the code in a debugger, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do? Also: can you reproduce the problem with hard-coded values for the `searchMin` and `searchMax` filters? How about, with just `console.log()` statements instead of building the HTML? All of these are steps you can take to reduce the scope of the problem. And the smaller the scope, the more likely it is that someone spots what's going wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you.. I did as you told me to console log everything i do in order not to get more errors and to find where is my mistake.. Finally I solved my problem.. Many thanks dear :)

Comment: Great to hear that you found the problem. If you think it's education for other users, I recommend posting your solution as an answer. If you don't think that's useful, I'll vote to close this as being no longer reproducible.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have posted solution for the above issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested in how I solved this problem. Below is the code:

```
let state;
 // get data from the cloud Database and display it on the home page
db.collection("properties").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  setupProp(snapshot.docs);
  state = snapshot.docs;


});
```

And here is the filter:

```
const filter = (items) => {
  const searchMin = Number(document.getElementById("min").value); // Min price search tap
  const searchMax = Number(document.getElementById("max").value); // Max price search tap
  const rentSale = document.querySelector(".rent-sale").value; // Rent/Sale search tap
  const citySelected = document.querySelector(".all-cities").selectedOptions[0].innerHTML; // City search tap
  const minRooms = document.querySelector(".min-rooms").value; // Min rooms search tap
  const maxRooms = document.querySelector(".max-rooms").value; // Max rooms search tap

  const itemsFilter = items
    .filter((item) => item.data().type === rentSale || rentSale === "0")
    .filter((item) => item.data().price > searchMin)
    .filter((item) => item.data().price <= searchMax || searchMax == 0)
    .filter((item) => item.data().city === citySelected || citySelected == "Choose...")
    .filter((item) => item.data().rooms >= minRooms || minRooms == 0)
    .filter((item) => item.data().rooms <= maxRooms || maxRooms == 0);

    return itemsFilter;
};

const filterForm = document.getElementById("filter-form");
filterForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const itemsFitler = filter(state);
  setupProp(itemsFitler);
  return false;
});
```